# Adding extra data to try-catch

Tags: c#

An application I'm working on is performing lots of parallel, background calculations on large data sets.

The global task responsible for these calculations is contained in a try-catch block to ensure the application doesn't go haywire, as well as for logging purposes.

However, this presents a minor problem - if an error occurs, I know where it happened, but because of the large amount of data I have no idea what was specific data the code was working on. This is further compounded by the fact that the application runs parallel calculations... This in turn means that manually debugging the code until I hit the problematic moment is... problematic.

What could I do in this case? I could write try-catch blocks for every possible calculation method, but there's a lot of those as well. Is there perhaps a simpler way?

EDIT:

The answers provided thus aren't what I'm looking for.

I know what information is provided in an exception. I know I can get the exact method where the error occurred by looking at the stack trace.

The problem isn't "where" the error occurs, but what data the method in question was working on when it happened. There's a lot of data, and a lot of methods, and only one, global try-catch.

Again, I could write dedicated try-catch blocks for each calculation method, but this is tedious. I wonder if there's a better way to do this.

It would be ideal if I could add some sort of tag to calculation methods which would, in the event of an error, indicate what data the method was working on. I don't know if this is at all possible however.

Comment: Log the data, whenever exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to [add additional data](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/using-exception-data-to-add-additional-information-to-an-exception/) to the `Exception` using the `Data` property. This way you don't have to create custom exceptions for each type of data you need to pass up the call stack.

```
try
{
    Calculate(someData);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.Data.Add("CalculationData", someData)
    throw;
}
```

**Edit:**

You can combine this with an AOP approach to make sure that all calls that you want to add the data to (or if you choose to log directly using interception) are intercepted and treated properly. See [this example](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2009/02/14/Simple-AOP-call-interception-with-DynamicProxy.aspx) for how it can be done.

Comment: Would not recommend catching "Exception", as you can handle exception which you do not expect, and which could leave the system in a vulnerable/corrupted state

Comment: This would work if the try-catch was in the same .cs and the same method where the exception happens. There's a lot of code, a lot of subclasses, and this doesn't work.

Comment: @Shaamaan - you could combine this with applying it cross cutting using AOP. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a stackframe object to find out more about the calling methods/functions. stick that in your catch and you can find out which method is giving you a problem

example

```
StackTrace stack= new StackTrace();           // get call stack
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stack.GetFrames();  // get method calls (frames)

// write call stack method names
foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);   // write method name
}
```

this will give you all the m

Answer (score 0):

Look at stack trace find out where the exception occurred originally and log it from there if viable.

If not create your own exception with any data you may want to pass up to the stack to the catch, and catch your custom exception.

Check out [MSDN: Designing Custom Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
public class NewCustomException : BaseException, ISerializable
{
    public NewException()
    {
        // Add implementation.
    }
    public NewException(string message)
    {
        // Add implementation.
    }
    public NewException(string message, Exception inner)
    {
        // Add implementation.
    }

    // This constructor is needed for serialization.
   protected NewException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   {
        // Add implementation.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the execution at the exact place in code where the exception was raised. This is a feature of Visual Studio debugger (can't use it in production). Go to menu Debug > Exceptions, and in new window check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Execution will now stop exactly when and where the exception is raised, and there you can inspect all the local data.